# Partial Update on MongoDB Error

Tags: mongodb, partial, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to have a partial update on one of my documents in MongoDB, using C# driver. I've followed the following posts:

[How do you update multiple field using Update.Set in MongoDB using official c# driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818964/how-do-you-update-multiple-field-using-update-set-in-mongodb-using-official-c-sh)

[Partial mongodb upsert using the c# driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7533481/partial-mongodb-upsert-using-the-c-sharp-driver)

I get the following error when trying to do the update: "Only classes can be mapped currently", in the AutoMapper CreateClassMap class, the type received is System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[MongoDB.Bson.BsonElement, MongoDB.Bson]], where it cannot be an interface.

The code I'm using is:

```
public void UpdateObjectByFields<T>(int id, Dictionary<string, object> modifiedFields)
    where T : class
{
    var collection = m_MongoDatabase.GetCollection<T>();
    var builder = new UpdateBuilder();
    foreach (var modifiedField in modifiedFields)
    {
        builder.Set(modifiedField.Key, modifiedField.Value.ToString());
    }
    collection.Update(Query.EQ("_id", id), builder);
}
```

where the T type is a valid collection in the Mongo.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Nir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this to work, apparently I was using some old dlls for the C# driver.
Fixed it by using the dlls from here:

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/downloads

Thanks,
Nir.